# Save Confusion Matrix in Python SKLEARN

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I'm generating 6 different confusion matrices for 6 different values of training data and I'm trying to save the generated confusion matrices as images. Unfortunately, when they save they keep saving as blank jpeg images; however, when I use show() to display them they are visible. Here is my code

```
for matrix in confusion_matrices:
        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.matshow(cm)
        plt.title('Problem 1: Confusion Matrix Digit Recognition')
        plt.colorbar()
        plt.ylabel('True Label')
        plt.xlabel('Predicated Label')
        fig.savefig('confusion_matrix'+str(learning_values.pop())+'.jpg')
```

I'm using the following libraries:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
from numpy import ravel, reshape, swapaxes
import scipy.io
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from random import sample
```

How do I efficiently save confusion matrices?

Comment: Where is `saveas` defined?  Just a guess: whatever `saveas` is, perhaps it requires that `plt.show()` has been called *before* `saveas` is called.  Have you tried `plt.savefig(...)`?

Comment: Hi Warren, thanks for pointing out that silly mistake I was making. However, now I have change it to the code above and it is still not saving. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the problem I was having. In case anyone is wondering, I modified the code to this and it resolved the problem.

```
for matrix in confusion_matrices:
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.matshow(cm)
    plt.title('Problem 1: Confusion Matrix Digit Recognition')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.ylabel('True Label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicated Label')
    plt.savefig('confusion_matrix'+str(learning_values.pop())+'.jpg')
```